# Why does console.log strip characters in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My `nodejs` code is reading from a stream and print it on the console. I found an interested behaviour that `console.log` strips characters for me. For example, below is the debug window on my nodejs.

[image]

From this debug window you can see that the value of `line` includes some `Ansi` encoding characters. But when I print it to terminal by `console.log`, I just got this output `> var prompt="dbenvy> "`. It doesn't have any `ansi` characters. I don't understand what cause this behaviour. I am not sure whether this is something to do with `console.log` or `terminal`

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `console.log` *does* output all characters, renderable or not.

Comment: I am using terminal from Mac OS shell

Comment: After some debug I found the problem may not relate to `console.log`. Instead the problem is the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if it was displaying the letters in the color or format indicated by the ANSI Escape codes.  Your debugger does not support ANSI Escape, but your terminal does have at least some support -- if it is not showing the colors, at least it knows not to dump the escape codes as text.

Comment: I mean the letter format not color. The terminal doesn't support showing text in colour.